# Initializing CPT TimberPosts in Twig from an ACF repeater

Tags: wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I've got an ACF repeater on an options page that accepts Post Objects and returns the post ID.

I'm trying to initialize them as TimberPosts in twig like so:

```
{% for group in Post(options.home_groups) %}

     <img class="group__thumb" src="{{ theme.link }}/assets/img/{{ group }}-front.png">

{% endfor %}
```

But the posts it creates are empty:

```
object(Timber\Post)#1568 (22) {
["ImageClass"]=>
string(12) "Timber\Image"
["PostClass"]=>
string(11) "Timber\Post"
["TermClass"]=>
string(11) "Timber\Term"
["object_type"]=>
string(4) "post"
["custom"]=>
array(0) {
}
["_content":protected]=>
NULL
["_permalink":protected]=>
NULL
["_next":protected]=>
array(0) {
}
["_prev":protected]=>
array(0) {
}
["_css_class":protected]=>
NULL
["id"]=>
NULL
["ID"]=>
NULL
["post_author"]=>
NULL
["post_content"]=>
NULL
["post_date"]=>
NULL
["post_excerpt"]=>
NULL
["post_parent"]=>
NULL
["post_status"]=>
NULL
["post_title"]=>
NULL
["post_type"]=>
NULL
["slug"]=>
NULL
["__type":protected]=>
NULL
}
```

I've tried returning the Post Object instead of the ID. If I return the Post Object, I can see that the WP post data appears correctly. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of `options.home_groups` to ensure it's giving you something useful. It should be either an array of `WP_Post`s or post IDs. Otherwise it should give you the `Post` objects you need.

The other potential issue I see is here:

```
/{{ group }}-front.png">
```

What is `{{ group }}` meant to output?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I realized that my problem was that `options.home_groups` returns a list of post IDs so i can't initialize the post there, it needs to happen for each `group` item.